# While making a retrofit2 post request, response body is null

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am getting the response body as null while making a POST request. I am passing data in the request body. I am making the call using Retrofit2. I have copied the relevant code snippets can you please help me out with the issue:

//JSON Body:

```
{
  "name" : "Anubhav Arora",
  "email" : "anubhavarora02@gmail.com",
  "password" : "anubhavpass123"
}
```

//Response:

```
{
  "message": "User Registered Successfully !!",
  "email": "anubhavarora02@gmail.com"
}
```

//End Point:

```
@POST("registeruser")
Call<UserRegistration> registerUser(@Body User user);
```

//post method call

```
private void registerUser(String username, String email, String 
password) {
    User user = new User(username, email, password);

    UserEndPoints apiService = APIClient.getClient()
            .create(UserEndPoints.class);

    Call<UserRegistration> call = apiService.registerUser(user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserRegistration>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserRegistration> call, Response<UserRegistration> response) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, response.body().getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserRegistration> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("TAG", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

//User Class

```
public class User {

private String name, email, password;

public User(String name, String email, String password) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

//User Registration Class

```
public class UserRegistration {

@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

//API Client

```
public class APIClient {

//10.0.2.2
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/v1/";
private static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add base url

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
       .baseUrl(url)
       .addConvertorFactory(new GsonConvertorFactory.create());


Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

UserEndPoints apiService = retrofit.create(UserEndPoints.class);
Call<UserRegistration> call = apiService.registerUser(user);

call.enque ......
```

Comment: I have added that in the APIClient class.